# Eclipse "File -> New -> SCA Component Project" option is not available

Tags: redhawksdr

Just getting started, installed redhawk IDE on CentOS 6.6 and then launched eclipse just like the manual says in section 3.3.1.  Manual says when you go to File -> New-> Project there should be an "SCA Component Project" but here is not.

Comment: I already tried commenting out the Dorg.omg.CORBA lines from the eclipse.ini, mentioned as a fix, but that did not work for me.

Comment: What version of java are you running?

Comment: What command did you type to run the IDE? Were there any errors on the console?

Comment: java -version command returns 1.7.0_85